Error "could not translate host name [database_name]" when running "php artisan queue:work"
While running "php artisan queue:work" its given error "could not translate host name [database_name]".
but something is odd, because the database_name is not the database i'm using in the project.
i have checked the .env DB_HOST, database.php and queue.php configuration but nothing wrong.
all other code is working fine and connect to the correct database. but only the queue is using incorrect database. my env QUEUE_CONNECTION=database.
i tried to run php artisan "optimize:clear" too, but nothing changed.
is there anything i miss?
